# USB drives show up twice in files (eOS 6)

Tags: files, usb, mount

I noticed that external drives (at least the ones I'm using) show up twice after mounting. When they are not mounted it's showing just once. Is this happening to someone else too?

Regards,

BootZ

Answer (score 0):

It's being discussed on github (very confusing all these places where we can file bugs or answer questions) https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1665